# Preprocessor in one Sampler is getting executed in the next sampler too

Tags: jmeter

In my testplan,I have one thread group.Inside that thread group i have number of http samplers.I have put one http sampler inside foreach sampler.Inside that http sampler i have one JSR223 preprocessor which adds one extra argument to the payload.

But that preprocessor is getting executed even in the next sampler outside foreach controller.Because of that,one extra vale is getting appendend to the payload and request gets failed due to invalid payload.

My doubt here is,
1.Why my JSR223 preprocessor inside one sampler is getting executed in next sampler?
2.If its the case,how can I restrict that preprocessor from executing outside its parent sampler?

Sorry for not sharing more details about code.I can't be able to expose my test plan due to company policy.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

PreProcessors obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so if you want it to be executed before a single Sampler - you need to put it **as a child of that particular sampler**

You can double check it using the following code:

```
log.info('Executing before: ' + sampler.getName())
```

[image]

as you can see the JSR223 PreProcessor is executed only before HTTP Sampler 1

In the above code:

- `log` - stands for [Log4jLogger](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.4/log4j-slf4j-impl/apidocs/org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLogger.html)
- `sampler` - is for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html)

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)